# Why can't I connect to PfSense via the switch?

Tags: vlan, trunk, pfsense

Our current firwall is deprecated and we decided to exchange it with an PfSense server. 
In my test setup I configured the interfaces as follows:

- igb0 = WAN

  - enabled
- igb1 = LAN (should be VLAN trunk port)

  - enabled
  - Interface ip: 192.168.1.1
- VLAN 104

  - enabled
  - parent interface: igb1
  - VLAN Tag: 104

After this I assigned the `VLAN 104 on igb1 0 lan` interface via "interface assignments" and gave the vlan the ip: 192.168.104.1/24

I configured our (Lancon ES-2126) switch like:

- Tag-based Group -> VID = 104

  - members -> port 1, port 2
  - untagged -> port 2
- Port 1 (should be VLAN trunk port)

  - Connected to PfSense LAN
  - PVID: 104
- Port 2

  - Connected to desktop
  - PVID: 104

I configured the vlan firewall rule(s) like this (allow all for test purposes)
[image: ![v]
and the lan like this
[image]

When I connect my desktop directly to the PfSense LAN port and give a static 192.168.1.x/24 ip, I can perfectly surf and access the PfSense interface. When I connect my PC via the switch to PfSense (as previously described) and change my static ip to 192.168.104.x/24 (or leave it in 192.168.1.x/24), I cannot access the web interface nor internet.

What do I do wrong? I have the idea that PfSense does nothing with the vlan at all?

---

**UPDATE**

`config.xml` as requested

```
<pfsense>
        <version>19.1</version>
        <lastchange></lastchange>
        <system>
                <optimization>normal</optimization>
                <hostname>bm_pfsense_axxwall01</hostname>
                <domain>localdomain</domain>
                <dnsserver>8.8.8.8</dnsserver>
                <dnsserver>8.8.4.4</dnsserver>
                <dnsallowoverride>on</dnsallowoverride>
                <group>
                        <name>all</name>
                        <description><![CDATA[All Users]]></description>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <gid>1998</gid>
                        <member>0</member>
                </group>
                <group>
                        <name>admins</name>
                        <description><![CDATA[System Administrators]]></description>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <gid>1999</gid>
                        <member>0</member>
                        <priv>page-all</priv>
                </group>
                <user>
                        <name>admin</name>
                        <descr><![CDATA[System Administrator]]></descr>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <groupname>admins</groupname>
                        <bcrypt-hash>$2y$10$jQvXNFjlnw3xT3g3MCQP3uBqSIHeu8sTiG1F5H1hk/M.qTM72S1A2</bcrypt-hash>
                        <uid>0</uid>
                        <priv>user-shell-access</priv>
                </user>
                <nextuid>2000</nextuid>
                <nextgid>2000</nextgid>
                <timeservers>2.pfsense.pool.ntp.org</timeservers>
                <webgui>
                        <protocol>https</protocol>
                        <loginautocomplete></loginautocomplete>
                        <ssl-certref>5ea6ebc012194</ssl-certref>
                        <dashboardcolumns>2</dashboardcolumns>
                        <port></port>
                        <max_procs>2</max_procs>
                </webgui>
                <disablenatreflection>yes</disablenatreflection>
                <disablesegmentationoffloading></disablesegmentationoffloading>
                <disablelargereceiveoffloading></disablelargereceiveoffloading>
                <ipv6allow></ipv6allow>
                <maximumtableentries>400000</maximumtableentries>
                <powerd_ac_mode>hadp</powerd_ac_mode>
                <powerd_battery_mode>hadp</powerd_battery_mode>
                <powerd_normal_mode>hadp</powerd_normal_mode>
                <bogons>
                        <interval>monthly</interval>
                </bogons>
                <already_run_config_upgrade></already_run_config_upgrade>
                <timezone>Europe/Amsterdam</timezone>
                <ssh>
                        <enable>enabled</enable>
                </ssh>
                <serialspeed>115200</serialspeed>
                <primaryconsole>serial</primaryconsole>
                <sshguard_threshold></sshguard_threshold>
                <sshguard_blocktime></sshguard_blocktime>
                <sshguard_detection_time></sshguard_detection_time>
                <sshguard_whitelist></sshguard_whitelist>
        </system>
        <interfaces>
                <wan>
                        <enable></enable>
                        <if>igb0</if>
                        <blockpriv></blockpriv>
                        <blockbogons></blockbogons>
                        <descr><![CDATA[WAN1]]></descr>
                        <ipaddr>dhcp</ipaddr>
                        <dhcphostname>bm_pfsense_axxwall01</dhcphostname>
                        <alias-address></alias-address>
                        <alias-subnet>32</alias-subnet>
                        <dhcprejectfrom></dhcprejectfrom>
                        <adv_dhcp_pt_timeout></adv_dhcp_pt_timeout>
                        <adv_dhcp_pt_retry></adv_dhcp_pt_retry>
                        <adv_dhcp_pt_select_timeout></adv_dhcp_pt_select_timeout>
                        <adv_dhcp_pt_reboot></adv_dhcp_pt_reboot>
                        <adv_dhcp_pt_backoff_cutoff></adv_dhcp_pt_backoff_cutoff>
                        <adv_dhcp_pt_initial_interval></adv_dhcp_pt_initial_interval>
                        <adv_dhcp_pt_values>SavedCfg</adv_dhcp_pt_values>
                        <adv_dhcp_send_options></adv_dhcp_send_options>
                        <adv_dhcp_request_options></adv_dhcp_request_options>
                        <adv_dhcp_required_options></adv_dhcp_required_options>
                        <adv_dhcp_option_modifiers></adv_dhcp_option_modifiers>
                        <adv_dhcp_config_advanced></adv_dhcp_config_advanced>
                        <adv_dhcp_config_file_override></adv_dhcp_config_file_override>
                        <adv_dhcp_config_file_override_path></adv_dhcp_config_file_override_path>
                        <ipaddrv6>dhcp6</ipaddrv6>
                        <dhcp6-duid></dhcp6-duid>
                        <dhcp6-ia-pd-len>0</dhcp6-ia-pd-len>
                        <adv_dhcp6_prefix_selected_interface>wan</adv_dhcp6_prefix_selected_interface>
                        <spoofmac></spoofmac>
                </wan>
                <lan>
                        <enable></enable>
                        <if>igb1</if>
                        <descr><![CDATA[LAN1]]></descr>
                        <spoofmac></spoofmac>
                        <ipaddr>192.168.1.1</ipaddr>
                        <subnet>24</subnet>
                </lan>
                <opt1>
                        <descr><![CDATA[WAN2]]></descr>
                        <if>igb2</if>
                        <blockpriv></blockpriv>
                        <blockbogons></blockbogons>
                        <spoofmac></spoofmac>
                        <enable></enable>
                </opt1>
                <opt2>
                        <descr><![CDATA[LAN2]]></descr>
                        <if>igb3</if>
                        <spoofmac></spoofmac>
                        <enable></enable>
                        <ipaddr>192.168.200.1</ipaddr>
                        <subnet>24</subnet>
                </opt2>
                <opt3>
                        <descr><![CDATA[VLAN_104]]></descr>
                        <if>igb1.104</if>
                        <enable></enable>
                        <spoofmac></spoofmac>
                        <ipaddr>192.168.104.1</ipaddr>
                        <subnet>24</subnet>
                </opt3>
        </interfaces>
        <staticroutes></staticroutes>
        <dhcpd>
                <lan>
                        <range>
                                <from>192.168.1.10</from>
                                <to>192.168.1.245</to>
                        </range>
                        <failover_peerip></failover_peerip>
                        <dhcpleaseinlocaltime></dhcpleaseinlocaltime>
                        <defaultleasetime></defaultleasetime>
                        <maxleasetime></maxleasetime>
                        <netmask></netmask>
                        <gateway></gateway>
                        <domain></domain>
                        <domainsearchlist></domainsearchlist>
                        <ddnsdomain></ddnsdomain>
                        <ddnsdomainprimary></ddnsdomainprimary>
                        <ddnsdomainkeyname></ddnsdomainkeyname>
                        <ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>hmac-md5</ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>
                        <ddnsdomainkey></ddnsdomainkey>
                        <mac_allow></mac_allow>
                        <mac_deny></mac_deny>
                        <ddnsclientupdates>allow</ddnsclientupdates>
                        <tftp></tftp>
                        <ldap></ldap>
                        <nextserver></nextserver>
                        <filename></filename>
                        <filename32></filename32>
                        <filename64></filename64>
                        <rootpath></rootpath>
                        <numberoptions></numberoptions>
                </lan>
                <opt3>
                        <range>
                                <from>192.168.104.10</from>
                                <to>192.168.104.200</to>
                        </range>
                        <enable></enable>
                        <failover_peerip></failover_peerip>
                        <defaultleasetime></defaultleasetime>
                        <maxleasetime></maxleasetime>
                        <netmask></netmask>
                        <gateway>192.168.104.1</gateway>
                        <domain></domain>
                        <domainsearchlist></domainsearchlist>
                        <ddnsdomain></ddnsdomain>
                        <ddnsdomainprimary></ddnsdomainprimary>
                        <ddnsdomainkeyname></ddnsdomainkeyname>
                        <ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>hmac-md5</ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>
                        <ddnsdomainkey></ddnsdomainkey>
                        <mac_allow></mac_allow>
                        <mac_deny></mac_deny>
                        <ddnsclientupdates>allow</ddnsclientupdates>
                        <tftp></tftp>
                        <ldap></ldap>
                        <nextserver></nextserver>
                        <filename></filename>
                        <filename32></filename32>
                        <filename64></filename64>
                        <rootpath></rootpath>
                        <numberoptions></numberoptions>
                </opt3>
        </dhcpd>
        <nat>
                <outbound>
                        <mode>advanced</mode>
                        <rule>
                                <source>
                                        <network>192.168.200.0/24</network>
                                </source>
                                <sourceport></sourceport>
                                <descr></descr>
                                <target></target>
                                <targetip></targetip>
                                <targetip_subnet></targetip_subnet>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <poolopts></poolopts>
                                <source_hash_key></source_hash_key>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588068438</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.200.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                                </created>
                                <updated>
                                        <time>1588068451</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.200.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                                </updated>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>127.0.0.0/8</network>
                                </source>
                                <dstport>500</dstport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <staticnatport></staticnatport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule for ISAKMP - localhost to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>127.0.0.0/8</network>
                                </source>
                                <sourceport></sourceport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <natport></natport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule - localhost to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>::1/128</network>
                                </source>
                                <dstport>500</dstport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <staticnatport></staticnatport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule for ISAKMP - localhost to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>::1/128</network>
                                </source>
                                <sourceport></sourceport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <natport></natport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule - localhost to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>192.168.1.0/24</network>
                                </source>
                                <dstport>500</dstport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <staticnatport></staticnatport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule for ISAKMP - LAN1 to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>192.168.1.0/24</network>
                                </source>
                                <sourceport></sourceport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <natport></natport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule - LAN1 to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>192.168.104.0/24</network>
                                </source>
                                <dstport>500</dstport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <staticnatport></staticnatport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule for ISAKMP - VLAN_104 to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                        <rule>
                                <interface>wan</interface>
                                <source>
                                        <network>192.168.104.0/24</network>
                                </source>
                                <sourceport></sourceport>
                                <target></target>
                                <destination>
                                        <any></any>
                                </destination>
                                <natport></natport>
                                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule - VLAN_104 to WAN1]]></descr>
                                <created>
                                        <time>1588064403</time>
                                        <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                                </created>
                        </rule>
                </outbound>
        </nat>
        <filter>
                <rule>
                        <id></id>
                        <tracker>1588067865</tracker>
                        <type>pass</type>
                        <interface>lan</interface>
                        <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
                        <tag></tag>
                        <tagged></tagged>
                        <max></max>
                        <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
                        <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
                        <max-src-states></max-src-states>
                        <statetimeout></statetimeout>
                        <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
                        <os></os>
                        <source>
                                <address>192.168.104.0/24</address>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <any></any>
                        </destination>
                        <descr></descr>
                        <updated>
                                <time>1588067865</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </updated>
                        <created>
                                <time>1588067865</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </created>
                        <disabled></disabled>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                        <type>pass</type>
                        <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
                        <descr><![CDATA[Default allow LAN to any rule]]></descr>
                        <interface>lan</interface>
                        <tracker>0100000101</tracker>
                        <source>
                                <network>lan</network>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <any></any>
                        </destination>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                        <type>pass</type>
                        <ipprotocol>inet6</ipprotocol>
                        <descr><![CDATA[Default allow LAN IPv6 to any rule]]></descr>
                        <interface>lan</interface>
                        <tracker>0100000102</tracker>
                        <source>
                                <network>lan</network>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <any></any>
                        </destination>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                        <id></id>
                        <tracker>1588069360</tracker>
                        <type>pass</type>
                        <interface>lan_interfaces</interface>
                        <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
                        <tag></tag>
                        <tagged></tagged>
                        <max></max>
                        <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
                        <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
                        <max-src-states></max-src-states>
                        <statetimeout></statetimeout>
                        <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
                        <os></os>
                        <source>
                                <any></any>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <any></any>
                        </destination>
                        <descr></descr>
                        <updated>
                                <time>1588069360</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </updated>
                        <created>
                                <time>1588069360</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </created>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                        <id></id>
                        <tracker>1588065927</tracker>
                        <type>pass</type>
                        <interface>opt2</interface>
                        <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
                        <tag></tag>
                        <tagged></tagged>
                        <max></max>
                        <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
                        <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
                        <max-src-states></max-src-states>
                        <statetimeout></statetimeout>
                        <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
                        <os></os>
                        <source>
                                <network>opt2</network>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <any></any>
                        </destination>
                        <descr></descr>
                        <created>
                                <time>1588065927</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </created>
                        <updated>
                                <time>1588065945</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </updated>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                        <id></id>
                        <tracker>1588064726</tracker>
                        <type>pass</type>
                        <interface>opt3</interface>
                        <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
                        <tag></tag>
                        <tagged></tagged>
                        <max></max>
                        <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
                        <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
                        <max-src-states></max-src-states>
                        <statetimeout></statetimeout>
                        <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
                        <os></os>
                        <source>
                                <network>opt3</network>
                        </source>
                        <destination>
                                <any></any>
                        </destination>
                        <descr></descr>
                        <created>
                                <time>1588064726</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </created>
                        <updated>
                                <time>1588065382</time>
                                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
                        </updated>
                </rule>
                <separator>
                        <lan_interfaces></lan_interfaces>
                        <opt3></opt3>
                        <opt2></opt2>
                        <lan></lan>
                </separator>
        </filter>
        <rrd>
                <enable></enable>
        </rrd>
        <revision>
                <time>1588142281</time>
                <description><![CDATA[admin@192.168.200.11 (Local Database): /system_advanced_admin.php made unknown change]]></description>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.200.11 (Local Database)]]></username>
        </revision>
        <gateways></gateways>
        <ifgroups>
                <ifgroupentry>
                        <members>lan opt2 opt3</members>
                        <descr><![CDATA[Internal lan interfaces]]></descr>
                        <ifname>lan_interfaces</ifname>
                </ifgroupentry>
                <ifgroupentry>
                        <members>wan opt1</members>
                        <descr><![CDATA[WAN interfaces]]></descr>
                        <ifname>wan_interfaces</ifname>
                </ifgroupentry>
        </ifgroups>
        <vlans>
                <vlan>
                        <if>igb1</if>
                        <tag>104</tag>
                        <pcp></pcp>
                        <descr><![CDATA[axx_intra]]></descr>
                        <vlanif>igb1.104</vlanif>
                </vlan>
                <vlan>
                        <if>igb1</if>
                        <tag>100</tag>
                        <pcp></pcp>
                        <descr><![CDATA[AxxCloud test network]]></descr>
                        <vlanif>igb1.100</vlanif>
                </vlan>
        </vlans>
</pfsense>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full (sanitized) configurations.

Comment: Sorry, the lists where broken for some reason, i fixed this. -- I hope that's what you mean else i don't know whats missing. For my feelings i have added all information. When you need more information, please be more specific so i can update my question. -- I'm pretty new to this all.. -- Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply list out the configurations in the terminal application, copy, then paste into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). There are many example of what that looks like, such as [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/65857/8499).

Comment: Thanks, i was "looking" for the place where i find such an "overview" of the settings and the console hint was useful. I added a (stripped) config.xml export to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fixed, for everyone who is curious to the issue...

After 3 days of testing and experimenting i found out that one of the cables is not 100%. After putting a new cable between PfSense and the switch everything works with the configuration like described in my question.